# Extract only first occurrence of character and all the numbers before and after hyphen

Tags: java, regex, string, stringbuffer

I got into this situation to write a generic function which can extract only first occurrence of the character and all the number from a string.

Input String (Say): ABC123-45DEF-GH67IJ9
Output String: A123-45D-G679

I have finalized an approach but the complexity of the program is high. There are two bad situations for me here:

1. I am getting incorrect output from my program.
   **Output:** A123-45D-G679- (This extra hyphen is the issue in the below code).
2. I need a better approach to get this done in a less complex way.

**Here is my code snippet:**

```
package Test;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class FirstLetterAndNumerics {

    static void firstLetterAndNumber(String string) {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
        String[] str = string.split("-");
        boolean flag = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

            ll.add(str[i]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < ll.size(); j++) {

            if (Character.isAlphabetic(ll.get(j).charAt(0))) {
                if (flag == false) {
                    sb.append("-");
                }
                sb.append(ll.get(j).charAt(0));

                for (int k = 1; k < ll.get(j).length(); k++) {
                    if (Character.isAlphabetic(ll.get(j).charAt(k))) {
                        flag = false;
                    } else if (Character.isDigit(ll.get(j).charAt(k))) {
                        sb.append(ll.get(j).charAt(k));
                    }
                }
                sb.append("-");
                flag = true;
            } else if (Character.isDigit(ll.get(j).charAt(0))) {
                sb.append(ll.get(j).charAt(0));

                for (int l = 1; l < ll.get(j).length(); l++) {

                    if (Character.isDigit(ll.get(j).charAt(l))) {
                        sb.append(ll.get(j).charAt(l));
                    } else if (Character.isAlphabetic(ll.get(j).charAt(l)) && flag == true) {
                        sb.append(ll.get(j).charAt(l));
                        flag = false;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(sb);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        firstLetterAndNumber("ABC123-45DEF-GH67IJ9");
    }
}
```

Comment: remove sb.append("-"); inside if block and write it on else bolck
if(alphabetcheck){}
elseIf(digitcheck){}
else{sb.append("-");}

Comment: @AbhishekMishra: adding else block to append "-" will not work, as "if" and "else if" blocks will only get the control, there is no other case for "else" block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `(\d*)([A-Za-z]{1})[A-Z]*(\d*)[A-Z]*(\d*)` regex for a much simpler method. It captures the correct parts in groups so you need to concatenate the groups.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/VoIDhV/1/) is how the regex works.

This code snippet appends the matches.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegexMatching {


    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        String testStr="ABC123-45DEF-GH67IJ9";
        String regEx = "(\\d*)([A-Za-z]{1})[A-Z]*(\\d*)[A-Z]*(\\d*)";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);

        StringBuilder outStr = new StringBuilder();

        while (matcher.find()) {                
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                outStr.append(matcher.group(i));
            }
            outStr.append("-");
        }

        outStr.deleteCharAt( outStr.length() - 1 ); // delete the extra "-"
        System.out.println(outStr.toString());
    }
}
```

prints:

```
A123-45D-G679
```

Lastly I'm not sure if what you want can be captured in a single group. This is the solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the string at the start on a hyphen. To make sure that the string contains characters uppercase chars and digits divided by hyphens, you could first use:

```
if(string.matches("[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+")) {
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/efX1ry/1)

Then you might use 2 capturing groups and make use of the `\G` pattern.

```
(?:(\b[0-9]*[A-Z])|\G(?!^))[A-Z]*([0-9]*)
```

That will match

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `\b[0-9]*[A-Z]` Word boundary, match 0+ digits and a single char A-Z
  - `)` Close group 1
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `[A-Z]*` Match 0+ chars A-Z
- `([0-9]*)` Capture **group 2**, match 0+ digits

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups `$1$2`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VUjc1m/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/nivfWS)

For example

```
static void firstLetterAndNumber(String string) {
    if(string.matches("[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+")) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\b\\d*[A-Z])|\\G(?!^))[A-Z]*(\\d*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("$1$2");

    }
}
```

Running `firstLetterAndNumber("ABC123-45DEF-GH67IJ9");` will output

```
A123-45D-G679
```